# Could not find i18n-0.6.7 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rubygems

I am trying to push my Rails app to Heroku and I am getting the following error:

```
Could not find i18n-0.6.7 in any of the sources
```

Gemfile.lock has the following line:

```
i18n (0.6.9)
```

When I do a Google search about my problem I found out that i18n-0.6.7  has been yanked. My project runs fine in development but when I push to production in Heroku is when I get this error.

Any ideas? Running bundle update, bundle install etc... has not yielded me any results.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is indeed that the version has been yanked, and therefore heroku cannot install it while compiling your push. The reason it works locally is because you still have that library on your machine.

Take a look at your `Gemfile.lock` and find instances of the i18n gem. When they are far indented, the lines above them in the hierarchy are the ones that list i18n as a dependency. Try updating those gems first.